# grouping floats to find most common general number

Tags: python, floating-point, grouping

im working with ebay, and i have a list of 100 prices of items that sold. what i want to do is separate each floating-point price into groups, and then count up the groups to sortof determine the most common general price for this item, so i can automate the pricing of my own item.

initially, i thought to separate prices by the $10 value, but i realized that this isnt a good method of grouping because prices can vary greatly because of outliers or unrelated items, etc.

if i have a list of prices like so: [90, 92, 95, 99, 1013, 1100]
my desire is for the application to separate values into:
{nineties:4, thousands:2}

but im just not sure how to tell python to do this. preferably, the simplest i can integrate this snippet into my code, the better!

any help or suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Why do not you just calculate the average price?

Comment: Look into clustering algorithms.

Comment: average price is not reliable, again because of outliers and unforeseen unrelated items that show up in a listing. in my opinion, i would get a more realistic price if i just use the most common price range that everyone else uses, compared to an 'average' price. not to mention, i wasnt able to figure out how to do the outliers so i had to cancel that idea anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The technique you use depends your notion of what a group is.

If the number of groups is known, use [*kmeans*](https://www.datascience.com/blog/introduction-to-k-means-clustering-algorithm-learn-data-science-tutorials) with `k==2`.  See [this link](https://github.com/rhettinger/modernpython/blob/master/kmeans.py) for working code in pure Python:

```
from kmeans import k_means, assign_data

prices = [90, 92, 95, 99, 1013, 1100]
points = [(x,) for x in prices]
centroids = k_means(points, k=2)
labeled = assign_data(centroids, points)
for centroid, group in labeled.items():
    print('Group centered around:', centroid[0])
    print([x for (x,) in group])
    print()
```

This outputs:

```
Group centered around: 94.0
[90, 92, 95, 99]

Group centered around: 1056.5
[1013, 1100]
```

Alternatively, if a fixed maximum distance between elements defines the groupings, then just sort and loop over the elements, checking the distance between them to see whether a new group has started:

```
max_gap = 100
prices.sort()
groups = []
last_price = prices[0] - (max_gap + 1)
for price in prices:
    if price - last_price > max_gap:
        groups.append([])
    groups[-1].append(price)
    last_price = price
print(groups)
```

This outputs:

```
[[90, 92, 95, 99], [1013, 1100]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think scatter plots are underrated for this sort of thing. I recommend plotting the distribution of prices, then choosing threshold(s) that look right for your data, then adding any descriptive stats by group that you want.

```
# Reproduce your data
prices = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series([90, 92, 95, 99, 1013, 1100]), columns=['price'])

# Add an arbitrary second column so I have two columns for scatter plot
prices['label'] = 'price'

# jitter=True spreads your data points out horizontally, so you can see
# clearly how much data you have in each group (groups based on vertical space)
sns.stripplot(data=prices, x='label', y='price', jitter=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Any number between 200 and 1,000 separates your data nicely. I'll arbitrarily choose 200, maybe you'll choose different threshold(s) with more data.

```
# Add group labels, Get average by group 
prices['price group'] = pd.cut(prices['price'], bins=(0,200,np.inf))
prices['group average'] = prices.groupby('price group')['price'].transform(np.mean)

   price  label price group  group average
0     90  price    (0, 200]           94.0
1     92  price    (0, 200]           94.0
2     95  price    (0, 200]           94.0
3     99  price    (0, 200]           94.0
4   1013  price  (200, inf]         1056.5
5   1100  price  (200, inf]         1056.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Naive approach to point in the right direction:

```
> from math import log10
> from collections import Counter

> def f(i):
>     x = 10**int(log10(i))  # largest from 1, 10, 100, etc. < i
>     return i // x * x

> lst = [90, 92, 95, 99, 1013, 1100]
> c = Counter(map(f, lst))
> c
Counter({90: 4, 1000: 2})
```

Comment: This cluster very well for data that spills over the arbitrary boundaries.  Given ``lst = [89, 90, 92, 95, 99, 100, 999, 1000, 1013, 1101]`` the ``f(i)`` function misclusters them to ``[80, 90, 90, 90, 90, 100, 900, 1000, 1000, 1000]``.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger All true, but the OP never asked for a sophisticated ml clustering algorithm. The naming 'nineties' and 'thousands' for the given input  indicates those random boundaries of multiples of the closest power of ten. And I did qualify it as 'naïve' ... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Assume that your buckets are somewhat arbitrary in size (like between 55 and 95 and between 300 and 366) then you can use a binning approach to classify a value into a bin range. The cut-off for the various bin sizes can be anything you want so long as they are increasing in size left to right.

Assume these bin values:

```
bins=[0,100,1000,10000]
```

Then:

```
[0,100,1000,10000]
  ^                    bin 1 -- 0    <= x < 100
      ^                bin 2 -- 100  <= x < 1000
           ^           bin 3 -- 1000 <= x < 10000
```

You can use [numpy digitize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html) to do this:

```
import numpy as np
bins=np.array([0.0,100,1000,10000])        
prices=np.array([90, 92, 95, 99, 1013, 1100])        
inds=np.digitize(prices,bins)
```

You can also do this in pure Python:

```
bins=[0.0,100,1000,10000]
tests=zip(bins, bins[1:])
prices=[90, 92, 95, 99, 1013, 1100]
inds=[]
for price in prices:
    if price <min(bins) or price>max(bins):
        idx=-1
    else:    
        for idx, test in enumerate(tests,1):
            if test[0]<= price < test[1]:
                break
    inds.append(idx)
```

Then classify by bin (from the result of either approach above):

```
for i, e in enumerate(prices):
    print "{} <= {} < {} bin {}".format(bins[inds[i]-1],e,bins[inds[i]],inds[i])

0.0 <= 90 < 100 bin 1
0.0 <= 92 < 100 bin 1
0.0 <= 95 < 100 bin 1
0.0 <= 99 < 100 bin 1
1000 <= 1013 < 10000 bin 3
1000 <= 1100 < 10000 bin 3
```

Then filter out the values of interest (bin 1) versus the outlier (bin 3)

```
>>> my_prices=[price for price, bin in zip(prices, inds) if bin==1]
my_prices
[90, 92, 95, 99]
```